# How to let FreeBSD get IP address automatically in VMware?

Tags: networking, ip, freebsd, vmware-workstation

I use [FreeBSD 10.2 VM image](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/VM-IMAGES/10.2-RELEASE/amd64/Latest/) in VMware workstation. Although I set bridge mode in VMware:
[image]

I find the OS can't get an valid `IP` address:
[image]
How can I let `FreeBSD` get `IP` address automatically in `VM`?

Comment: You mean it should be getting an address via DHCP? Your post is quite unclear. Also, your post is not about professional networking, so it should be moved to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean DHCP, then either select the DHCP option when installing FreeBSD or edit the `/etc/rc.conf` file and set:

```
ifconfig_em0="DHCP"
```

If you use a bridged network, you will need to have a DHCP service running on the connected network. If you use a NAT network, then VMware provides the DHCP service.